# Can I use a comma instead of an em dash before the phrase "all without proper notice" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, em-dash

Would the first sentence using a comma be acceptable? Can this sentence be broken into two sentences, as in 2., or would that leave a sentence fragment? Or is 3. proper in its use of the em dash?  Would someone mind explaining why a comma or separate sentences would be improper? I'm having a hard time grasping it. Thank you.

1. I had to clean up the apartment, put the electricity service in my name, and find a new roommate, all without proper notice.
2. I had to clean up the apartment, put the electricity service in my name, and find a new roommate. All without proper notice.
3. I had to clean up the apartment, put the electricity service in my name, and find a new roommate―all without proper notice.

Comment: The modern trend is towards *less* punctuation - including both *discarding* commas, and reducing "heavier" elements such as full stops and semicolons to "lighter" commas. So I'd say your first version is fine, even if some more traditional grammarians would object. I don't they'd complain about the other two, but it's essentially a stylistic choice between all three, imho.

Answer (score 1):

There is no verb in 'all without proper notice', and hence example 2 contains a fragment.

Examples 1 and 3 are fine.

The difference between the em dash and the comma is that the former separates a strong interruption from the rest of the sentence, whereas the latter separates a weak interruption.

In our case here, the interruption seems strong, and my preference is hence the em dash.

http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/hyphenanddash/dash

Comment: Using a sentence fragment in 2 would be very common in casual English, and also serves to provide emphasis of the last phrase. So it's not wrong except in very formal contexts.